# How to set maven plugin to run in git bash shell in Intellij Idea?

Tags: git, bash, maven, intellij-idea, git-bash

I have a lot of modules in IntelliJ IDEA Project (which was defined as maven module).

Each of these modules can be run successfully but only from Git Bash command Prompt.

Note from an editor: the original sentence was both incorrectly formatted and phrased as a possible part of the question, leading to some confusion. Here it is:

> This each module can be run successfully only from *git-bash Command Prompt*?

So the question is: Can I run each module from Intellij GUI view as in Git Bash which is not the default windows command line? Does it mean from the maven plugin view [GUI]?

Is there any workaround not to run from the Terminal view?

Comment: Which command do you use to "run module", can you give some exampe?

Comment: Simply `mvn clean install'. If you set up your terminal that you will run them from a git-bash perspective, it will build that module successfully. If you run this module from Intellij-GUI perspective it will fail. I have defined in one module that several commands must be run by using shell/bash. In my example "module" runs command  make, which is the unix makefile. I can't run this module in Windows Command Prompt. I have no idea how this default maven plugin execute simply maven command. Can I change it somehow ?

Answer (score 1):

The question is not clearly formulated but I sounds like the OP wants to use git bash as the IntelliJ terminal. For anybody looking for an answer to this:

'Settings --> Tools --> Terminal' and in 'Shell Path' Field:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\sh.exe" --login -i
```

Or whatever command you use to launch your git bash

**UPDATE AFTER COMMENT BY OP:**

Menu -> Run -> Edit Configurations... -> Add new configuration -> Maven

Name: whatever

Working directory: your module directory

Command line: clean install

Then you can run the maven goal from the menu in the upper right corner
[image]

Comment: I asked about executing maven task from Intellij idea by clicking selected module. Not from terminal by providing command in cli.